# Dynamic navigation with php

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

Hi I am building a site directory and I'm having a little trouble understanding how to use the     `$_GET['page']` function

I understand you can use this to navigate across sites which are dynamically made, in fact I have a site which uses it currently but I did not create that set of code and don't understand the logic behind it..

I know how I will handle the navigation - the homepage will contain sites with a link to both their website and to a listing on my site. The listing url will contain the category and the ID of the site.

I want it to look like `domain/category/siteid` or like `domain/index.php?cat=2&id=58`

I understand I will probably need to use htaccess to change the url to look like the first example..

So anyway, the url will contain both the site ID and category which I want to then use to associate with the dynamically loaded page, with the relevant category and site listing.

This seems to be the standard way of loading pages in PHP but I've been unable to find a good guide on how to do it, I will also need to read the data from the url to make a database call so if anyone could explain how I can read the url to get the listing id and category it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Luke

Comment: It has very little to do with PHP. Every web script can use these features, and the use of `.htacces` is correct

Comment: But how do I go about loading the pages using the $_GET feature, I want to have a link which dynamically goes to the associated listing using the data from the url, the site category and the siteid

Comment: As @byf-ferdy answered, your question covers the _absolute basic_ usage of `PHP`. Using an URL like `example.com?id=58` will give you a variable in `PHP` called `$_GET` with an index `id` and has the value `58`. If you wish to use _readable URLs_ like `example.com/id/58` then you have to use `htaccess` to rewrite an URL from `example.com?id=58` to `example.com/id/58`. There are so many questions here on SO covering both topics, examples and tutorials online, that it's pretty much a waste of time waiting for someone that comes a long answering your questions.

Comment: I see, my apologies the issue I was having was how to set the categories and id into the url, it seems you can just set it by defining it before you write the url so I've done `href='?cat=".$category."&id=".$id."'` so all I have to do is use the $_GET feature to obtain the separate variables?

Comment: Make sure you escape the variables correctly with [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your question more or less yourself. The parameters from the URL are available in PHP in the `$_GET` array. For your example the category would be `$_GET['cat']` (would return 2) and the ID would be `$_GET['id']` (would return 58).

Take care of [SQL-Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also see other [global variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: Looks simple enough thank you for the response I'll have a go and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the heads up on SQL-injection too

Comment: Just did it, much much easier than I was expecting thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                    <?
                    $first_query = "SELECT * FROM navigation_menu WHERE `status` ='active'";
                    $first_menu = $db->select($first_query);
                    for($a = 0 ; $a < count($first_menu) ; $a++)
                    {?>
                        <li><a href="general.php?id=<?=$first_menu[$a]['id']?>&general=m"> <?=$first_menu[$a]['navigation']?> </a>

                                <?$second_query = "SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE nav_menu_id=".$first_menu[$a]['id']." AND `status` ='active'";
                                $second_menu = $db->select($second_query);

                                if(count($second_menu) > 0)
                                {?>
                                    <ul>
                                    <?for($b = 0 ; $b < count($second_menu) ; $b++)
                                    {
                                        if($second_menu[$b]['sub_nav_menu'] != '')
                                        {?>
                                            <li> <a href="general.php?id=<?=$first_menu[$a]['id']?>&sid=<?=$second_menu[$b]['id']?>&general=s"><?=$second_menu[$b]['sub_nav_menu']?></a>

                                                <?$third_query = "SELECT * FROM sub_child_menu WHERE nav_menu_id=".$first_menu[$a]['id']." AND sub_nav_id=".$second_menu[$b]['id']." AND `status` ='active'";
                                                $third_menu = $db->select($third_query);

                                                if(count($third_menu) > 0)
                                                {?>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <?
                                                        for($c = 0 ; $c < count($third_menu) ; $c++)
                                                        {?>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a href="general.php?id=<?=$first_menu[$a]['id']?>&sid=<?=$second_menu[$b]['id']?>&cid=<?=$third_menu[$c]['id']?>&general=c">
                                                                    <?=$third_menu[$c]['child_menu']?>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        <?}?>
                                                    </ul>
                                                <?}?>
                                            </li>
                                        <?}
                                    }?>
                                </ul>
                            <?}?>
                        </li>
                    <?}?>
                </ul>
```

Comment: This looks about 10x more complex than is necessary and I'm not sure it actually does what I asked, but thank you anyway